# Proper field orders for covering index - MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, covering-index

Is there a standard order to create a covering index for a table in MySQL? Meaning if I have  query that has a where clause, order by and the fields in the select statement, in what order would I have the fields to the index to properly create a covering index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A covering index takes a list of columns in a comma separated list.  This list is traversed/reviewed starting at the left side.  If the left most column is not used, the index is not used.  Meaning, having a column list like:

```
col_a, col_b, col_c
```

If the query does not contain a reference to `col_a`, it won't be used.  If the order is changed to:

```
col_c, col_b, col_a
```

...then `col_c` needs to be referenced in the query.  Continuing to use the second covering index column example, `col_b` or `col_a` don't have to be in in the query but the evaluation moves column by column, from left to right.

Column references for index use can be in the following clauses:

- SELECT
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY

Reference:

- [Multiple-Column Indexes, MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: So if I had a where clause then add the fields in the where clause in the index then all the fields in the select statement?

Comment: @John: The column references can be across any of the clauses I mentioned.  That said, the existence of an index does not guarantee it will be used - table statistics play a role in index selection.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Optimization 7.5.2 Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) says:

> MySQL uses multiple-column indexes in such a way that queries are fast when you specify a known quantity for the first column of the index in a WHERE clause, even if you do not specify values for the other columns.

The example on the linked page also states, that an index is *not used*, if you do not specify a value for the first column in the index.